# How can I get the name and id from my java bean?

Tags: java, spring

I am trying to run a test function to get the name and id of my bean from the config file. I have tried everything I can think of up until now and no luck. I get about 40 lines of errors that I have no idea how to read. I am certain it is something simple but I am just not connecting the dots. How can I fix this?

```
package com.intraedge.spring.springcore;

class Employee {

    private int id;
    private String name;

//  public int getId(int args) {
//      id = args;
//      return id;
//  }

       public void setName(String name){
           this.name = name;
       }

       public String getName(){
           return this.name;
       }


}
```

```
package com.intraedge.spring.springcore;

import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class Test {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ClassPathXmlApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("config.xml");
    Employee emp = (Employee)ctx.getBean("emp");
    System.out.println("Name: "+emp.getName(name.value));
//    System.out.println("Id: "+emp.getId(3));
  }
}
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
  xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
  xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" 
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

  <bean name="emp" class="com.intraedge.spring.springcore.Employee">
    <property name="id">
      <value>20</value>
    </property>

    <property name="name">
      <value>Casandra</value>
    </property>
  </bean>

</beans>
```

Comment: *Unrelated:* Delete this line: `Test test = new Test();` --- If you ever tried to create an instance of `Test`, that line would cause a `StackOverflowError`.

Comment: *"I get about 40 lines of errors"* Show us the error so we can help interpret it for you. Also show us the config file.

Comment: Sorry, here is the error: Line 5 in XML document from class path resource [config.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: http://springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd; lineNumber: 5; columnNumber: 65; TargetNamespace.1: Expecting namespace 'http://springframework.org/schema/beans', but the target namespace of the schema document is 'http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans

Comment: It saying about your config.xml is getting error while parsing. Can you post your config.xml?

Comment: I added the config file above. This line: http://springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd" also has an error ( red x ) next to it but does not say what the issue is.

Comment: I think you're missing the first line in that XML.

Comment: It's there, I just missed when copying it here. I'll add it in here.

Comment: Your first line might missing "<" charater
And you also might missing <beans> element

Comment: Your namespaces are wrong, they are all missing the `www.` prefix. All 7 `http://springframework.org/` should be `http://www.springframework.org/`

Comment: Ok I made all the suggested updates but the any argument i add to getName function indicates an error.

Comment: You missed the first one in line 2, which is actually the one the error message is mentioning.

Answer (score 0):

After updating the namespaces like suggested, there was a new error relating to the getter/setter of the bean ID. I fixed it by adding in the proper getter/setter functions and removing any arguments from the function calls.

```
public void setId(int id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public int getId() {
            return this.id;
        }

       public void setName(String name){
           this.name = name;
       }

       public String getName(){
           return this.name;
       }
```